# Mixing separately compiled objects

Tags: c++, gcc

Let's I have a class `class Drawable`. It could have many members, member functions, parent classes, or could be very simple. For the sake of this example that is not important. Also, let's say it is some kind of GUI element.

Then, let's assume I have a rendering engine, which is provided as a GCC library `engine.a`. That library contains `class Screen`, which has method `void Screen::add(const Drawable & child)`. All I have are headers and library itself. In my application I instantiate `Screen`, create few `Drawable` objects and `add` them to `Screen`.

My question:
Could my GCC toolchain (or my GCC toolchain's version) create different memory layout for `Drawable` objects than in compiled `engine.a`? Standard does not define it and it is an implementation detail. Either way it will link perfectly. How can I know that and how can I be sure about correct behaviour?

P. S. I mostly use ARM GCC toolchain for Cortex-M architecture. **But my question is not limited to that**.

P. P. S. If you have any thoughts related, but not related to GCC specifically, please feel free to share.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
**This question is about compiler internals ONLY.**

Comment: Your library and code should be compiled in at least the same major version of the compiler.

Comment: Yes. You could very well have ODR violations

Comment: For non standard layout types: Only with the same compiler + settings is it well defined. Thats basicly your choices, a) use standard layout types only or b) same compiler+settings

Comment: @NathanOliver Theoretically, sure. In practice the C++ ABI of major compilers hasn’t changed in so long that you can link even ancient libraries without issues. ABI changes are almost taboo for compiler vendors. This is in fact a major sticking point, since it leads to nontrivial (~5-fold) performance regressions in standard library implementations that would require changing the ABI to fix. *Maybe* this will change within the next five years (resistance against ABI compatibility is slowly forming) but so far I’m still doubtful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Could you provide a reference for your _~5-fold_ statement? I'd love to read more about that.

Comment: @nada Apologies, I misremembered: it’s threefold. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1863r0.pdf

Comment: @KonradRudolph Actually it's not threefold but _"5% to 10%"_. It is 2 to 3-fold just for the case of 'unordered_map/std::hash'. Interesting read though, thanks a lot!

Comment: @nada Yes, I was referring to the extreme case. Of course it’s not threefold for *everything* (maybe I should have written “up to”, but I thought that was implied). Notably, it’s also not 5% to 10% for everything, that’s just a (crudely estimated) average for all ABI related performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

> Could my GCC toolchain (or my GCC toolchain's version) create different memory layout for Drawable objects than in compiled engine.a?

Yes. Consider the following silly example:

```
struct Drawable
{
   #ifdef ENABLE_COUNTERS
   int counter = 0;
   #endif

  // ...
};
```

Perhaps one person compiled with `-DENABLE_COUNTERS` and someone else didn't. This violates the One Definition Rule. Or perhaps one toolchain was compiled where integers were 32 bits and another where they were 64 bits.

The linker, in order to be fast, will not complain; it will just throw away all but one definition, which could wreak all kinds of havoc (virtual function calls especially could get weird as the offsets become wrong).

> How can I know that and how can I be sure about correct behaviour?

gcc has [`flto-odr-type-merging`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and `-Wodr` that can help you out when you compile.

Google's [ASAN](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerOneDefinitionRuleViolation) can also examine memory layouts to ensure they're identical.

---

Regarding your edit on compiler internals only.

Please refer to GCC's guidance on ABI stability: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

*Roughly* speaking. Each major compiler version has a new ABI. Later minor releases with the same major release almost always are compatible.

You can control which ABI you target with `-fabi-version`

Comment: My question was not about that different compilation options can affect output. Question is about compiler internals ONLY.

Comment: Then you are interested in ABI stability between releases of GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

Answer (score 3):

The memory layout, along with a lot of other things, is part of the ABI.  One of the other things is the name mangling scheme.  Although you should only link together object compiled for the same ABI, ABI designers try to use different mangling scheme so that accidentally linking objects compiled with different ABI usually result in unresolved symbols.

GCC has a command line flag to control the ABI: `-fabi-version` but the ABI depends also of some other options like `-fno-exceptions` and obviously the standard library implementation for the standard types.

Comment: Name mangling is not related here. I am not changing function prototype so that it does not affect anything. Linker will 100 % pass perfectly. See my edit in original post.