# Is it crucial to know by which compiler a specific binary generated in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, binary, static-libraries, abi

I want to know if it is important to know which compiler was used to compile a specific library in C++? Because I heard about ABI compatibility and I am curious to know if it does matter or not!

For example can I download binaries of OpenCV (including dlls and libs) for Windows which were compiled with MSVC and use them in another code which is compiled with MinGW?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58644069/1968 (Based on the timing, I’m assuming that the other question triggered this one?)

Comment: I not sure that it is appropriate for a "duplicate" VTC but the question linked by @KonradRudolph does provide a good answer to *this* question.

Comment: It is essential if the code is `c++`. Also it used to be that different versions of Visual C++ were incompatible with each other. That was before VS2015 all major versions of VS were considered binary incompatible with a different major version and usually incompatible with most other compilers (except the Intel one)

Comment: I am sure there is a duplicate for this.

Comment: So @drescherjm why there is many examples in the internet which using MSVC binaries generated and import it into MinGW project and vice versa? How we can ensure that there is ABI incompatibility or not?

Comment: It works for `c` code or code with a `c` only interface but not `c++`. There will be a different implementation of the standard library in `c++` code and other ABI incompatibilities. Also the internet is littered with a lot of very bad advice.

Comment: Related: [http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands)

Comment: Compilers can match on some stuff and not on other. F.ex. they can have the same way to push function arguments but very different vtables layouts and even diff placement for the vptr in an instance (esp. complicated MI cases).

Answer (score 6):

It depends:

If a library's interface is C++-based, it will need to match the C++ ABI of the compiler the user of the library is using. This usually means that the user needs to be using the same compiler with a close version number.

If the library exposes only a "flat" C-based interface, even if it's internally written in C++, it only needs to match the C ABI of the compiler that the user of the library is using. The C ABI is usually defined by the platform and common across compilers.

Note that a "flat" interface could be "reconstituted" into a C++ class-based interface using "wrapper" classes defined in headers. In this case, as long as the library binary only exposes C-compatible functionality, it will still only be dependent on the C ABI.

Additionally as an aside, on Windows only, there is functionality called "COM" which provides a standard ABI to allow programs to use objects written using different compilers and even different languages entirely. However, COM classes are not ordinary C++ classes and their creation and use is quite different.

In the specific case of OpenCV, I've never used it but, looking at the filename of the download of the latest version "opencv-4.1.1-**vc14_vc15**.exe"; this indicates that it contains libraries for use with Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler versions 14 and 15 (aka Visual Studio 2015 and 2017). If you want to use it with MinGW (which uses the GCC compiler) then you'll need to get an unofficial build or compile it from source yourself.

Comment: In case of VC++, in addition to the vc-version number one should match other aspects like x86/x64, debug/release, shared/static CRT, unicode/MBCS, calling convention, exception handling mode (/EH), LTGC, pdb format, etc.

Comment: @Stu Thank you so much! How can we check if multiple binaries are compatible with each other?

Comment: Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I don't know of any tool to check for binary compatibility. You may find some tool to identify the compiler that compiled a binary.